# How can I use IdentityServer3 External Authentication to login a Local User?

Tags: identityserver3

Having worked through the IdentityServer3 MVC tutorial [here](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/mvcGettingStarted.html) I have a working sample application where I can log in as 'bob', or I can log in with any google account.

What I am trying to work out is, say bob has an additional field 'GoogleId':

```
public static class Users
{
    public static List<InMemoryUser> Get()
    {
        new InMemoryUser
        {
            Username = "bob",
            Password = "secret",
            Subject = "1",
            GoogleId = "60a71ff098f6509cbd4fbda2f495eacb",

            Claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName, "Bob"),
                new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.FamilyName, "Smith"),
                new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.Role, "Geek"),
                new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.Role, "Foo")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I log in with Google, if the incoming subject claim matches a User's GoogleId, log in with the local user account.

The [IdentityServer3.AspNetIdentity project](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.AspNetIdentity) must be doing this as the Asp.Net Identity has external logins keyed off local user accounts. However I can't use the Asp.Net Identity user model as I'm working in a legacy application. I can't understand the code there well enough to apply it to my situation.

Is there a sample or tutorial somewhere that demonstrates this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to implement the AuthenticateExternalAsync method in the UserService. You can use the ExternalIdentity provided to find the local user by your own mechanism and then set an AuthenticateResult.

[Here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/CustomUserService/CustomUserService/ExternalRegistrationUserService.cs#L28) is a good example of a custom UserService authenticating externally.